# django message framework not show messages

Tags: python, django

I write a message board,When user leave message and success back to the page
I want to alert('Thank you')  to let user know it's success.

But the message didn't show

I add this in my setting ,still not work
`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",)`

Please help me ,Thank you .

views.py

```
def maininfo(request):
    return render(request, 'zh_tw/maininfo.html',)

def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Thank you')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/maininfo/#5thPage')
        return render(request, "zh_tw/maininfo.html",{'form': form,'anchor':'#5thPage'})
```

urls.py

`urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^maininfo/$', views.maininfo, name='maininfo'),)`

template: zh_tw/contact.html
(this is an anchor page included by zh_tw/maininfo.html)

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <p{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'core:create_post' %}" method="POST" id="create_post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if not form %}
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="你的名字">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="你的電子信箱">
    </div>
    <textarea placeholder="你想說的話" name = "message" id="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">送出</button>
    {% endif %}
    {% if form %}
        {% if form.errors %}
            <div>
                <span  style="color:red ; font-weight:bold">
                {{ form.name.errors }} {{ form.email.errors }} {{ form.message.errors }} </span>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="你的名字"  value="{{form.name.value }}" >
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="你的電子信箱" value="{{form.email.value}}">
            </div>
            <textarea placeholder="你想說的話"   name = "message" id="message">{{form.message.value}}</textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">送出</button>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the same message block in the redirection page, `return HttpResponseRedirect('/maininfo/#5thPage')` 
the message will be displayed normaly !

Comment: Thank you!it's the css problem! You let me figure it out.